# Browser's back button doesn't trigger parseRouteInformation and throws Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.error Flutter

Tags: flutter-web, flutter-navigation

I'm switching to `Navigator 2.0` and I can manage to change page with navigation buttons in my `NavigationBar` widget, but when hitting browser's back or forward button the page won't update dough displayed url does.
If I press it a second time dough it does go back but throws the `Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.` error.

```
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.

The following GlobalKey was specified multiple times in the widget tree. This will lead to parts of the widget tree being truncated unexpectedly, because the second time a key is seen, the previous instance is moved to the new location. The key was:
- [LabeledGlobalKey<NavigatorState>#781da]
This was determined by noticing that after the widget with the above global key was moved out of its previous parent, that previous parent never updated during this frame, meaning that it either did not update at all or updated before the widget was moved, in either case implying that it still thinks that it should have a child with that global key.
The specific parent that did not update after having one or more children forcibly removed due to GlobalKey reparenting is:
- Builder
A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 251:49  throw_
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2939:15                           <fn>
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2963:16                           finalizeTree
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 884:7                               drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 319:5                             [_handlePersistentFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1143:15                           [_invokeFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1080:9                            handleDrawFrame
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 996:5                             [_handleDrawFrame]
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 1003:13                           invoke
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 157:5                             invokeOnDrawFrame
lib/_engine/engine.dart 440:45                                                <fn>
```

all my widgets, wether they're stateless os stateful, have the `const WidgetName({Key key}) : super(key: key)` constructor, and when instantiating them I never pass the parent's key to the child..

I tried to remove `Key` from widgets' constructors but still I get the error..

I removed the key from Navigator in `RouterDelegate` and the duplicate error is gone, but still it takes 2 back button presses to go back to previous page, and editing the url manually throws the error:

```
Could not navigate to initial route.
The requested route name was: "/retailers"
There was no corresponding route in the app, and therefore the initial route specified will be ignored and "/" will be used instead.
```

In my overridden `parseRouteInformation` I set prints, which show when app starts but not when I press browser's back or forward button.

Can you spot why `RouteInformationParser` is not parsing the previous route and throws the `Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.` error?

I checked and the one in `RouterDelegate` is the only one I declared.
Is there anything else you need to see about my app?

this is my RouterDelegate:

```
class AppRouterDelegate extends RouterDelegate<RoutePath>
    with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin<RoutePath> {

  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;
  AppState appState = AppState();
  AppRouterDelegate() : navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>() {
    appState.addListener(notifyListeners);
    print('appState.addListener(notifyListeners) called');
  }
  @override
  RoutePath get currentConfiguration {
    print(
        'RouterDelegate.currentConfiguration appState.selectedPage is ${appState.selectedPage}');

    switch (appState.selectedPage) {
      case '/':
        return HomePath();
      case CyclistsLandingRoute:
        return CyclistsPath();
      case RetailersLandingRoute:
        return RetailersPath();
      case MapRoute:
        return MapPath();
      case AboutRoute:
        return AboutPath();
      case TermsOfServiceRoute:
        return TermsOfServicePath();
      case PrivacyPolicyRoute:
        return PrivacyPolicyPath();
      case PrivacySettingsRoute:
        return PrivacySettingsPath();
      case CommunityGuidelinesRoute:
        return CommunityGuidelinesPath();
      case LegalNoticeRoute:
        return LegalPath();
      default:
        return HomePath();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Delegate build");
    return Navigator(
        key: navigatorKey,
        pages: [
          MaterialPage(
              child: WebsitePageDisplay(
            appState: appState,
          ))
        ],
        onPopPage: (route, result) {
          print("onPopPage");
          if (!route.didPop(result)) {
            return false;
          }
          if (appState.selectedPage != null) {
            appState.selectedPage = null;
          }

          notifyListeners();
          return true;
        }
        );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setNewRoutePath(RoutePath path) async {
    print('RouterDelegate.setNewRoutePath path is ${path.selectedPath}');
    appState.selectedPage = path.selectedPath;
  }
}
```

this is my RouteInformationParser:

```
class AppRouteInformationParser extends RouteInformationParser<RoutePath> {
  @override
  Future<RoutePath> parseRouteInformation(
      RouteInformation routeInformation) async {
    print(
        'AppRouteInformationParser.parseRouteInformation called for ${routeInformation.location}');
    final Uri uri = Uri.parse(routeInformation.location);
    if (uri.pathSegments.length > 0) {
      print(
          'Uri.segments.first is: ${uri.pathSegments.first}, uri.path is: ${uri.path}');
    } else {
      print('AppRouteInformationParser uri has no segments and is $uri');
    }

    switch (routeInformation.location) {
      // switch (uri.pathSegments.first) {
      case '/':
        print('AppRouteInformationParser.urlSegment switch case : /');
        // return CyclistsPath();
        return HomePath();
      case CyclistsLandingRoute:
        print(
            'AppRouteInformationParser.routeInformation.location switch case: /cyclists');
        return CyclistsPath();
      case '/retailers':
        print(
            'AppRouteInformationParser.routeInformation.location switch case: /retailers');
        return RetailersPath();
      case '/map':
        print(
            'AppRouteInformationParser.routeInformation.location switch case: /map');
        return MapPath();
      case AboutRoute:
        print(
            'AppRouteInformationParser.routeInformation.location switch case: /about');
        return AboutPath();
      case TermsOfServiceRoute:
        print(
            'AppRouteInformationParser.routeInformation.location switch case: /terms-of-service');
        return TermsOfServicePath();
      case PrivacyPolicyRoute:
        print(
            'AppRouteInformationParser.routeInformation.location switch case: /privacy-policy');
        return PrivacyPolicyPath();
      case PrivacySettingsRoute:
        print(
            'AppRouteInformationParser.routeInformation.location switch case: /privacy-settings');
        return PrivacySettingsPath();
      case CommunityGuidelinesRoute:
        print(
            'AppRouteInformationParser.routeInformation.location switch case: /community-guidelines');
        return CommunityGuidelinesPath();
      case LegalNoticeRoute:
        print(
            'AppRouteInformationParser.routeInformation.location switch case: /legal-notice');
        return LegalPath();

      default:
        print(
            '### default AppRouteInformationParser.routeInformation.location switch case ## default: /');
        return HomePath();
    }

  }

  @override
  RouteInformation restoreRouteInformation(RoutePath path) {

    print(
        'AppRouteInformationParser.restoreRouteInformation called for path ${path.selectedPath}');

    switch (path.selectedPath) {
      case '/':
        // case CyclistsLandingRoute:
        print('restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/');
      case '/cyclists':
        // case CyclistsLandingRoute:
        print('restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /cyclists');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/cyclists');

      case '/retailers':
        print('restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /retailers');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/retailers');
      case '/map':
        print('restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /map');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/map');
      case '/about':
        print('restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /about');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/about');
      case '/terms-of-service':
        print(
            'restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /terms-of-service');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/terms-of-service');
      case '/privacy-policy':
        print(
            'restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /privacy-policy');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/privacy-policy');
      case '/privacy-settings':
        print(
            'restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /privacy-settings');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/privacy-settings');
      case '/community-guidelines':
        print(
            'restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /community-guidelines');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/community-guidelines');
      case '/legal-notice':
        print(
            'restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /legal-notice');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/legal-notice');
      default:
        print(
            'restoreRouteInformation  ### Default RouteInformation.location: /cyclists');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/cyclists');
    }
  }
}
```

and this is AppState:

```
class AppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  String _selectedPage;
  AppState() : _selectedPage = null;

  String get selectedPage => _selectedPage;

  Widget get selectedWidget {
    switch (selectedPage) {
      case CyclistsLandingRoute:
        return CyclistLanding();
        break;
      case RetailersLandingRoute:
        return RetailerLanding();
        break;
      case MapRoute:
        return CityMap();
        break;
      case AboutRoute:
        return AboutUs();
        break;
      case TermsOfServiceRoute:
        return TermsOfService();
        break;
      case PrivacyPolicyRoute:
        return PrivacyPolicy();
        break;
      // case PrivacySettingsRoute:
      //   return PrivacyPolicySettings();
      //   break;
      case CommunityGuidelinesRoute:
        return CommunityGuidelines();
        break;
      case LegalNoticeRoute:
        return LegalNotice();
        break;
      default:
        return CyclistLanding();
        notifyListeners();
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set selectedPage(String page) {
    print('AppState setting selectedPage to $page');
    _selectedPage = page;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem:

In main.dart build method I was  returning a `MaterialApp` with a `MaterialApp.router` as the home instead that a `MaterialApp.router` directly and move all the parameters into it.
Everything works just as expected now.

## wrong way :

```
  AppRouterDelegate _routerDelegate = AppRouterDelegate();

  AppRouteInformationParser _routeInformationParser =
      AppRouteInformationParser();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: '',
      color: Colors.red,
      localizationsDelegates: [
        const AppLocalizationsDelegate(),
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', 'US'),
        const Locale('it', 'IT')
//        const Locale('es', 'ES'),
      ],
      localeResolutionCallback:
          (Locale locale, Iterable<Locale> supportedLocales) {
        for (Locale supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
          if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode ||
              supportedLocale.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
            print('Web device Locale is $locale');
            return supportedLocale;
          }
        }
        return supportedLocales.first;
      },
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MaterialApp.router(
          routeInformationParser: _routeInformationParser,
          routerDelegate: _routerDelegate),
    );
  }
```

## correct way is :

```
AppRouterDelegate _routerDelegate = AppRouterDelegate();

  AppRouteInformationParser _routeInformationParser =
      AppRouteInformationParser();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routeInformationParser: _routeInformationParser,
      routerDelegate: _routerDelegate,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: '',
      color: Colors.red,
      localizationsDelegates: [
        const AppLocalizationsDelegate(),
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', 'US'),
        const Locale('it', 'IT')
//        const Locale('es', 'ES'),
      ],
      localeResolutionCallback:
          (Locale locale, Iterable<Locale> supportedLocales) {
        for (Locale supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
          // if (UniversalPlatform.isWeb) {
          if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode ||
              supportedLocale.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
            print('Web device Locale is $locale');
            return supportedLocale;
          }
        }
        return supportedLocales.first;
      },
      // localeListResolutionCallback: ,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Wow you just saved me from a long debug session. Thanks!